# Почему текст выводится даже когда условие не выполняется?

Tags: python, функции

Я написал функцию `yes_no` для проверки введённого значения, но при вводе пустой строки она возвращает значение `True`, и текст выводится. Как исправить ошибку?

```
def yes_no():
    while True:
        val = input().strip().lower()
        if val in 'даyes':
            return True
        if val == '':
            return False
        else:
            print('Введено некорректное значение. Введите "да", "yes", или оставьте поле ввода пустым.')
print('Если хотите увидеть текст, введите "да" или "yes", если хотите продолжить, оставьте поле ввода пустым.')
if yes_no():
    print('qwerty...')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать и оператор `in`, но проверять вхождение строки в список:

```py
if val in ['да', 'yes']:
    return True
```

Comment: Как вариант можно использовать.

Answer (score 1):

*Я столкнулся с данной проблемой при разработке одного проекта, хотел задать вопрос на StackOverflow, однако после детального изучения кода решил проблему сам. Тем не менее посчитал нужным выложить его вместе с ответом, возможно, кому-нибудь пригодится.*
А проблема в том, что **строка, не содержащая ни одного символа, является подстрокой любой строки**. И строка `'даyes'` не исключение. Функция, как мы знаем, прерывается после возврата значения. Можно  использовать логический оператор `or`, чтобы решить проблему:

```
def yes_no():
    while True:
        val = input().strip().lower()
        if val == 'да' or val == 'yes':
            return True
        if val == '':
            return False
        else:
            print('Введено некорректное значение. Введите "да", "yes", или оставьте поле ввода пустым.')
print('Если хотите увидеть текст, введите "да" или "yes", если хотите продолжить, оставьте поле ввода пустым.')
if yes_no():
    print('qwerty...')
```

Comment: `if val in == 'да'`???

Comment: Исправил, не заметил при редактировании)

Answer (score 1):

Так, небольшая ремарка: пустое значение обычно проверяют в питоне так:

```
if not val:
    return False
```

Это просто единообразный стиль - так проверяют на пустую строку, пустой словарь и т.п.

И да, в данном случае лучше проверять это первым делом.

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще просто поменять местами:

```
    if val == '':
        return False
    elif val in 'даyes': # и в данном случае логично использовать elif,
        return True
```

Comment: Но тогда можно ввести `a`, и выведет `True`

Comment: Да. Оно и в исходном коде именно так. @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8

Comment: Конкретно проблему решает, но оставляет более глубокую, которую питонист отметил.