# Как сделать else не в функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

*Хотел сделать калькулятор на питоне и проверку на то соответствует ли ответ пользователя, и есть такой вопрос, пайтон мне выдает ошибку:*

```
    else:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

*при коде:*

```
while True:
    
    def code():
        
        print(Back.RED)
        what = input("Что делаем? (+, -, *, /, %, ^): ")
        
        if what != ("+" and "-" and "*" and "/" and "%" and "^"):
            print("Не понял тебя")
        code()
        
    else:
    print(Back.MAGENTA)
    a = float(input("Введите первое число: "))
    print(Back.CYAN)
    b = float(input("Введите второе число: "))
    if what == "+":
        c = a + b

    if what == "-":
        c = a - b

    if what == "*":
        c = a * b

    if what == "/":
        c = a / b

    if what == "%":
        c = a % b

    if what == "^":
        c = a ** b

    print(Back.GREEN)
    print(Style.BRIGHT)
    print("Результат: " + str(c))

    input()
```

*объясните пожалуйста что неправильно, сильно не ругайте, это моя вторая программа после hello world*

**Заранее спасибо за ответ!**

Comment: У вас else находится на ровне с функцией, надо добавить таб

Comment: Пробовал, всё равно выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Не могли бы вы дать чуть больше кода, чтобы я мог вопроизвести проблему, добавьте через [edit]

Comment: После `hello world` рекурсивную функцию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Советую изучить базовый синтаксис Python. Он отличается от многих других ЯПов строгостью написания отступов - они являются обозначением начала и конца блоков (в других ЯПах обычно для этого используется {}).

[Здесь неплохое объяснение](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Indentation)

В Вашем случае легче показать на места, где что-то написано правильно, чем указать ошибки, тем не менее:

1. Условие `what != ("+" and "-" and "\*" and "/" and "%" and "^")` будет истинно только при `what == "^"`, и по своей структуре неверно. Нельзя вынести `what !=` как общий множитель за скобку. Правильно: `what != "+" and what != "-" and what != "*" and what != "/" and what != "%" and what != "^"`
2. В строке 10 происходит рекурсия, а так как выхода из функции нет нигде, она становится бесконечной и непрерывной.
3. Блок else идёт вообще непонятно (особенно для интерпретатора) где, а главное - для чего и к чему относится

Если приложить фантазию для осмысления сути программы и устранить базовые ошибки, то получится примерно так:

```py
while True:
    
    def code():
        
        what = input("Что делаем? (+, -, *, /, %, ^): ")
        if what != "+" or what != "-" or what != "*" or what != "/" or what != "%" or what != "^":
            print("Не понял тебя")
        
        else:
            a = float(input("Введите первое число: "))
            b = float(input("Введите второе число: "))

            # Здесь Ваша реализация калькулятора в зависимости от значения what
            # ...
            # ...

    code()
```

Ответ на вопрос в комментариях:
В текущей реализации оно так и будет происходить, но можно сделать и по-другому - внести while True в функцию так:

```py
while True:
    what = input("Что делаем? (+, -, \*, /, %, ^): ")
            if what != "+" or what != "-" or what != "\*" or what != "/" or what != "%" or what != "^":
                print("Не понял тебя")
            else:
                break
```

P.S. И да, как написали ниже, действительно можно условие сделать
`if what not in ('+-*/%^')`

Comment: Мне кажется, проверку значения `what` лучше сделать вот так: 'if what not in ('+', '-', '*',  '/', '%', '^'):' Это будет выглядеть лаконичнее, и повысится удобочитаемость кода.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Как сделать так, чтобы, если `what` не равен (+ - * / % ^), код говорил `("не понял тебя")` и переспрашивал снова: `what = input("Что делаем? (+, -, *, /, %, ^): ")`

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можите использовать else если до него нету if, потому что else подразумвает что если не if или elif, то else, добавте перед else таб и все что идет дальше через два таба
P.S. добавьте после code() таб

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать!

Answer (score -1):

Так ещё лаконичней:

```
if what not in ('+-*/%^'):
```

В примере выше с циклом while будет работать как вы хотите.

Comment: Вы проверяете, не входит ли `what` в строку `+-*/%^`, но если ввести пустую строку, то случится ошибка, так как пустая строка является подстрокой любой строки. [Посмотрите этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1357674/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f/1357675#1357675)